# Does Microsoft has an API like Google Places API?

Tags: maps, google-places-api, bing

[image: this is the data im trying to get]

This image is from Bing Maps and my goal is to get the information in red (wheelchair access) through the api.

Does anyone know if microsoft has any API that returns this data?

Thank you!

I tried to search here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a Bing Maps REST service. Example documentation for a local search:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/local-search

However, it does not appear that the data returned has the details you're looking for. I am just looking for Bing Maps API myself and came across your question so perhaps there are other endpoints that reveal such information.

125k queries per year free for the basic license - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/licensing/licensing-options/